# Using thonny IDE, apparently the pyserial module is not working for me, any suggestions?

Tags: python, pyserial, thonny

This is the problem I recieve when it is run:

`AttributeError: module 'serial' has no attribute 'Serial'`

The code is:

```
import serial

connection = serial.Serial('COM3', 115200)

while True:
    data = connection.readline()
    print(data)
```

I was expecting it to run.

Comment: Have you named a script `serial.py`?  *That* would be found by `import serial` instead of the actual module.

Comment: Show the full traceback of the error as properly formatted text (formatted as code) in the question.